# Android - why webview redirect to webbrowser

Tags: android, android-webview

i try a simple webView appication. and this is my code :

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://eepis-its.edu");
}

public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient{
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()){
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

and, when i try to click hyperlink on that site, i redirected to mobile browser. why its happen?
what i wanted is, when i click hyperlink its show on webview too.

please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to override the standard behavior, which launches the browser when links are clicked. Use a [`WebViewClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)'s [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)). There is an [example of this](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) in the SDK (copied below for convenience).

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

...then you just call `someWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());`.