# Android WebView 302 Redirect - Honeycomb

Tags: java, android, redirect, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm working on an Android application that uses a WebView and some 302 redirects to track link clicks.  On Android 2.3.3, a 302 redirect passes through

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
```

correctly, but on Honeycomb 3.2.2 only the initial URL passes through, and the 302 redirect never shows up as being requested.  I attempted the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941516/android-why-webview-redirect-to-webbrowser), and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9493323/211780), but neither of those fixes the problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738328/shouldoverrideurlloading-in-webview-for-android-not-running#answer-6739042) must help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method [public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest (WebView view, String url)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String))

Maybe, helpful for you.

Comment: Usage: [here](https://bricolsoftconsulting.com/fixing-the-broken-honeycomb-and-ics-webview/)