# How to load the application in Web-View in a specific browser like Chrome or Firefox in Android

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android, i am doing an application where i need to load our existing application in Web-View on Tablet. In the Tablet when i load my application by using Web-View my application is getting loaded in default browser.

How can i load my application in a specific browser[like Chrome or Firefox] in Web-View on Tablet?

Comment: I think web-view is not a browser, it is a view to show webcontent.

Answer (score 3):

> In the Tablet when i load my application by using Web-View my application is getting loaded in default browser.

`WebView` is a widget that you place in the UI of one of your activities. It is not the default browser.

If you are calling `loadUrl()` on the `WebView`, and it is bringing up the default browser, that is because the Web server is issuing a redirect. You can add a `WebViewClient` to your app to handle this, as is discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941605/115145

> How can i load my application in a specific browser[like Chrome or Firefox] in Web-View on Tablet?

If you really do want to load content into a Web browser, you let the *user* choose what browser the *user* wishes to use. Typically, this will happen automatically when you launch a URL (e.g., via `startActivity()` on an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`) -- if there is more than one browser, and they have not set a default, the user will be presented with a chooser to pick which browser they wish to use.